# Google Places API Reviews, changing the sorting order?

Tags: google-places-api, review

Well according to the docs https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceDetails the Google Places API is now able to display 5 reviews from a specific location which is pretty awesome!
But these reviews are rolled out by "Most Helpful" which is the default order on a Google + Local page.

I think it would be a bit more helpful if these review where rolled out by latest so you can indicate when a review was last posted.

Is there any consideration in changing the reviews sorting order? 
Or is there some way I can figure out when a new review gets posted via the API?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to figure out if a new review gets posted via the Places API. If you believe this or sorting of reviews would be useful feature you can submit a 'Places API - Feature Request' [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Answer (score 0):

The sorting method to use when returning reviews. Can be set to most_relevant (default) or newest.

- For most_relevant (default), reviews are sorted by relevance; the service will bias the results to return reviews originally written in the preferred language.
- For newest, reviews are sorted in chronological order; the preferred language does not affect the sort order.

Google recommends that you display how the reviews are being sorted to the end user.